# How to display an image in a div?

Tags: html, css

I have been having some trouble with a website I am attempting to create. my aim is to have a div called "header" that will contain a background image that spans the top of the page. However when I code it as (To the best of my knowlage it should be coded) I am just left with a blank page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my css

```
#header{
    background-image: url("header.jpg"); 
    50% 0 repeat; 
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: you put those values to a property like `background-position` or `background-size` and `background-repeat`.

Comment: Try setting `display: block; width: 100%; position: relative; height: 90px;` to the `#header div.`

Height and width since there is no content inside your `#header div`. If there's no content, it won't expand if height and width aren't setted, and your background won't show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write something inside header div or set the height.

```css
#header{
    background-image: url("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8bb98c95963486c35af93203a53f4c98?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"); 
  background-position: 50% 0;
  background-size:cover;
  font-size:2em;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">Hello</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: as @cocoa mentioned in a comment, the correct `repeat` and `position` properties would be `background-position: 50% 0;` and `background-repeat: repeat;`

Comment: So @CodeRomeos the reason why is wasn't working is because for the div to display the content it needed some content -.- (If this is the case I feel a bit silly) is there a way of having it display the image without the need for text.

Comment: Set the height of the div for showing the background-image without the text.

Comment: Anyway I can make the background image scale to the size of the window its displayed on?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this. It's a fast method

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background-image:url(http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02690/Anne-Guichard_2690182k.jpg); font-size:2em; background-size:cover; color:#fff; background-position: 50% 0;">This is div with a background picture</div>
</body>
```

Hope this was helpful